# Sequelize - how to select and join two tables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables that are not connected by any primary/foreign key and i want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT u.statusId, 
       u.createdAt,
       p.name, 
       p.method 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN posts p ON u.task = p.task
```

How can i do it?
I tried looking at some other answers but for some reason it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If `task` is your primary/foreign key then Its's seem oOk

Comment: In the `u` table, yes. In the `p` table it's just a "regular" field, not primary/foreign.

Comment: but name is `task` on both table?

Comment: Yes. (.........)

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues running that query, only problem is if you have more than 1 to 1 record. in which case it will result in multiple items appearing.

Comment: How would i run it though?

Comment: Are you using SQL server management studio to connect to the database? if so press F5 on the query or the little green play button. I'm not sure how to answer your question as it's a bit broad...here's a small [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgyO2NN5wNA) I found quickly